# Moving a Compability Level 80 db under SQL Server 2005 instance to SQL Server 2000 Instance (by not using db script)

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, restore

I have a database with the compatibility level 80. However, it is on a SQL Server 2005 Instance.

I need to move that database to SQL Server 2000 Instance.

I can not use the script of db because it contains lots of linked server, missing objects, same server db references which is painful to handle.

How can I move db to SQL Server 2000 without using dbscript?

Comment: Even though it's running in compatibility mode 80, the database *file* is a 2005 file. A 2000 server cannot understand such a file (nor a 2005 backup, etc).

Comment: then, dbscript is the only way, right? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Yep, scripting it is.